# How to send a json object (or other data structures) with Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am slowly working my way into Paramiko and by now am able to connect to a remote host and send entire files. I am now facing the challenge to send structured information (ideally JSON objects, strings or file blocks) to the remote machine.

Could anyone please provide me with pointers on how to achieve this with Paramiko in a Python-only implementation (i.e.: I don't want to do fall back to including bash operations like executing `echo $string` or the like).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. You can't send JSON objects via SSH, this is nonsense. However, you can dump a JSON object to a file and then send it. So either you tell us what you try to achieve or use the JSON module (included in Python) to dump your files.

Comment: Thanks, @septi. My ultimate goal is to transfer file blocks securely across a network. This process will involve the exchange of structured meta-information such as checksums etc. as well. So far, I was under the impression this could all be done via ssh as a secure protocol. Please correct me if I am wrong ... and in case it's not obvious: I don't have too much experience in that domain yet :)

Comment: SSH is a secure shell, which utilises a secure connection to allow shell access to a remote machine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). What you're looking for is a TLS/SSL socket connection (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html). You'll of course need to implement a client and a server.

Comment: OK ... thanks for the clarification, @septi! This is helpful information indeed. I have looked into socket programming a bit by now and will check out the reference to the secure socket connections you provided. I am hoping that the send() method should get me a long way from here!

Comment: Alright, you'll figure it out, I'm sure ; ) It's not that hard. Just look at some examples of client/server socket communication (there are tons of examples out there) and then implement the secure layer.

Comment: @septi: The socket connection you suggested does exactly what I need. Great stuff! Thanks again.